# Redirecting to "show" view of a model object when searched by attributes (NOT id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, turbolinks

I have a form where users look for a particular bill by some attributes of that bill, namely the "Congress Number", "Bill Type", and "Bill Number", as in 114-H.R.-67 . I want to "show" the appropriate bill, but to do that I have get the appropriate bill model in a separate action which I've called "find_by_attributes". Inside this action I perform:

```
@bill = Bill.find_by( params ).first
```

which correctly acquires the appropriate bill's id.

Now I simply want to redirect to the "show" method of this bill, as in the url

```
".../bills/[@bill.id]"
```

As of right now, at the end of my "find_by_attributes" action I do

```
redirect_to bills_path(@bill)
```

which correctly loads the show.html.erb with @bill, but does not change the url (the url is still shows the "find_by_attributes" action followed by a long query-string, instead of the clean "/bills/[:bill_id]".

How can I restructure my code to achieve the neat redirect that I desire?

Full code below:

THE FORM

```html
<%= form_tag("bills/find_or_create", :method => :get ) do |f| %>
  <%# render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= fields_for :bill do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.label :congress, 'Congress (i.e. 114)' %>
    <%= ff.number_field :congress, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= ff.select :bill_type, options_for_select(
        [['House of Representatives', 'hr'],
         ['Senate', 's'],
         ['House Joint Resolution', 'hjres'],
         ['Senate Joint Resolution', 'sjres'],
         ['House Concurrent Resolution', 'hconres'],
         ['Senate Concurrent Resolution', 'sconres'],
         ['House Resolution', 'hres'],
         ['Senate Resolution', 'sres']]
        )
    %>

    <%= ff.label :bill_number, 'Bill number (i.e. 67)' %>
    <%= ff.number_field :bill_number, class: 'form-control' %>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

THE CONTROLLER ACTIONS

```html
  def find_by_attributes
    @bill = Bill.where(bill_params).first_or_create(bill_attributes)
    redirect_to bills_path(@bill)
  end

  def show
    puts bill_params
    if params[:bill]
      @bill = Bill.where(bill_params).first_or_create do |bill|
        bill.attributes = bill_attributes
      end
    else
      @bill = Bill.find(params[:id])
    end
    @subjects = Subject.where("bill_id = ?", @bill[:id])
    @bill_comments = Comment.where("target = ?", @bill[:id])
  end
```

ROUTES FILE

```
...
  resources :bills do
    get :find_by_attributes
  end
...
```

**EDIT**

I make use of the turbolinks gem in my rails application.

Comment: What does rails log show? (when you do a redirect it shows a redirect status code and two consecutive requests) What does the browser show on the network tab? (when you receive a redirect, it shows the url to where you are being redirected) does it still happen if you disable turbolink just to test this?

Comment: Everything shows 200, loads fine, no surprises except that the URL is not what it ought to be. Disabling turbolinks kills the link, so I take it redirect_to is part of the turbolinks gem.

Comment: What do you mean with "kill" the "link"? it's a form, and what does "kill" mean? any error somewhere? `redirect_to` is a rails method, nothing to do with turbolink (turbolink works client side, not serverside). your route says "find_by_attributes" but your form points to "find_or_create". Copy your rails logs too, it looks like you are not pointing the right action (you should use a named route instead of the hardcoded url)

Answer (score 0):

the thing I see here is that you are calling to

```
redirect_to bills_path(@bill)
```

that in theory is not the show path, you just need to remove the "s"

```
redirect_to bill_path(@bill)
```

and as a side comment, in this line, you don't need the first part, because find_b, finds the first record matching the specified conditions, you can remove that part.

```
@bill = Bill.find_by( params )
```

Comment: I deleted the unnecessary 's' as you suggested but that did not solve the problem. At this point the only issue is that the URL does not change when I redirect. It seems like it should be an incredibly simple fix...

Comment: Then please add your routes file to the question

Comment: I added the part that establishes routes pertaining to bills. If this is insufficient let me know, and I'll add more.

Comment: In theory it has to work with your routes. Maybe you have a before action/filter in your controller? Please make the request and see at the log server in the console and add this to the question